# How to subscribe to human workflow events in Oracle SOA Suite 11g?

Tags: oracle, events, oracle11g, bpel, soa-suite

I'm using BPEL processes in Oracle SOA Suite 11g with some human tasks. I need to do some stuff when a task is claimed or released. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

PS: [Here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2326327&tstart=0) is the link to my post in Oracle's forums

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Java callbacks or Business event callbacks.

Please check these link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_hwfmodel.htm#BABJCDIG

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_hwfmodel.htm#BABDBAJJ